# Are there "method" versions of the javascript Object functions: keys, values, entries, fromEntries?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, method-chaining

I like the style of array method chaining with map, filter, etc, but often find myself having to "break" that style in order to use `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`. I discovered the Object instance method `getOwnPropertyNames` which seems comparable to `Object.keys`, if less elegantly named, but I'm wondering about instance versions of the other static Object methods.

For example, instead of writing:

```
const foo = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(bar).map(myCoolFunction))
```

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
const foo = bar.keys()
  .map(myCoolFunction)
  .toObjectFromEntries()
```

Comment: The Object methods were added fairly recently, and added as "static" methods to avoid breaking any of the massive amount of JavaScript code in the wild.

Comment: One of the main reasons, why i am waiting for https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

Comment: @ASDFGerte also relevant is the [bind syntax proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) which allows free methods to easily be executed against an instance. In essence replacing `someMethod.call(someInstance, arg1, arg2)` with `someInstance::someMethod(arg1, arg2)`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much movement on it :/

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that pipeline operator reference, @ASDFGerte. Didn't realize how well trodden this ground was.

Comment: Sadly, the first commit to that proposal's repo was "Nov 9, 2015". I understand it's complex, and making a wrong decision means having to deal with the consequences for decades (can't undo), but i'd still wish it would finally get somewhere usable.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yeah. The more function-y proposals have been dragging on, unfortunately.